# TypeError: Can't convert 'float' object to str implicitly

Tags: python

TypeError: Can't convert 'float' object to str implicitly

```
print("\nYou will make {:.2f}".format(score * live - BIN))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't convert a float to a str implicitly.  :)

You need to wrap the numeric part in `str`.  Or, better yet, use string formatting:

```
print("\nYou will get {}".format((score + power) - BIN))
```

Comment: Tried that! Didn't work. Came up with this error: **TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'str'**

Answer (score 1):

Your `(score + power)` expression results in a `float` value, and you are trying to concatenate that to a string with `+`. You cannot do that, as that would require an implicit conversion of the value to a string.

Either use a comma when printing:

```
print("\nYou will get", (score + power) - BIN)
```

and have the `print()` function convert this for you, or use string formatting (which gives you more control over how the float is formatted):

```
print("\nYou will get {:.2f}".format((score + power) - BIN))
```

or, applying that to the full program:

```
BIN = float(input("\nEnter the buy-it-now price of the item: £"))
Postage = float(input("\nEnter the shipping & handling cost of the item: £"))

eBayFee = (BIN + Postage) / 10
PayPalFee = ((3.4 * BIN) / 100) + 0.2

print ("\nYou will be charged £{:.2f} eBay fees and £{:.2f} PayPal fees.".format(eBayFee, PayPalFee))

print("\nYou will make {:.2f}".format(BIN - eBayFee - PayPalFee))
```

Note that it's the formatting that rounds of the numbers now to 2 decimal positions. I've also corrected the formula; presumably the 'profit' is the Buy-it-now price minus the eBay and PayPal fees, not the fees combined minus the BIN.

Comment: @Mo.: so `BIN` is string too? What do you expect `score + power - BIN` to *do*? Should `BIN` be a number too?

Comment: @Mo.: You didn't show us where `score`, `power` and `BIN` **come** from, so all we can do is give you (educated) guesses as to how to solve your problem. Give us more information on those 3 values and we can help you better.

Comment: @Mo.: Your new error messages tells us that `BIN` is **not** a number, it is a string. Can you edit your question to show us where `BIN` comes from?

Comment: @Mo.: In Python 3, `input()` returns a *string*. Convert that to a number with `float(BIN)` first.

Comment: @Mo.: again you are adding `str` and `float` somewhere.

Comment: @Mo.: INstead of this back-and-forwarding, **edit your question** to show us where the values *come from*.

Comment: @Mo.: you didn't read my answer very well; use *commas* to pass multiple values to the `print()` function, that way the function will turn your values into strings. But `str.format()` would still be better here.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the float to a string.

```
print("\nYou will get "+  str(score + power - BIN))
```

Comment: I tried converting it to a string but I get this error: **unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'**

Comment: @Mo. Then you didn't put the `str` function around `BIN` as well.

Comment: @Mo. I see. If `BIN` is a string it makes no sense to subtract it from something anyway. That is your problem.